# Calling an object-specific function on a STL vector of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, function, vector, polymorphism, virtual

So I have a class hierarchy that essentially has `Entity` class as the parent abstract class and a bunch of other classes that derive from it, such as `Door`, `Player`, `Ground`, etc.

I also have a three-dimensional `vector` that stores the pointers to objects of type `Entity` and I fill up this `vector` with the derived objects. 
Within the `Door` class I have a method called `isOpen()` that simply returns a `bool`. This function is specific to the `Door` class and is neither found in `Entity` class nor in any other derivations of it (as I don't need to check whether, for example, a `Ground` object is open or not).

Now, knowing that there exists an object of type `Door` at `vector` position `i`, `j`, `k`, I would like to call the method `isOpen` like so: `vector[i][j][k]->isOpen()`. Unfortunately, when I do this, the compiler returns **`class Entity has no member named isOpen()`**. This is understandable since the function `isOpen()` is exclusive to the `Door` class, but what can I do in order to make this sort of call possible?

Comment: Don't just  *tell* us about your code; ***showing*** it is *much* more productive. Second, [`dynamic_cast<>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) might be of some use to you. Don't just throw it in, read about how to use it **first**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a down cast to a `Door *` first. However, in order for this down cast to be type safe, you should use `dynamic_cast<Door *>()`. If `Entity` does not already have a virtual method, you can add a virtual destructor.

```
class Entity {
    //...
    virtual ~Entity () {}
};

void foo (Entity *e) {
    //...
    Door *door = dynamic_cast<Door *>(e);
    if (door) {
        if (door->isOpen()) {
            //...
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Cast the Entity down to a door: `static_cast<Door*>(vector[i][j][k])->isOpen()`.

Long answer:

Your design isn't proper if you need to know a specific derived type is at a specific location.  Fixing this might be as simple as moving the `isOpen()` function up to Entity with a default implementation returning `true`.  Or it could require a whole rethinking of the code that works with the members of `vector`.

Comment: If the entity being pointed to is *not* in fact a `Door` or a derivation of `Door` further down the hierarchy, this is **undefined behavior** and will most-assuredly crash. `static_cast<>` is *not* the casting type to use here. See its description [in this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) for why.

Comment: You would want to use `reinterpret_cast`, not `static_cast` - though that method is NOT a recommended approach.  The long answer is more on track - fix the design.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggesting to use a type cast.
In terms of the class redesign, do you have any suggestions as to how I would go about doing that? It seems that a vector with multiple objects of the same parent class is integral to my program :(

Comment: Is dynamic_cast with a null check not more appropriate ? The design does sound a bit flawed. Not sure about moving IsOpen to the base class though, as IsOpen does not sound applicable to every type. Rethinking the entire approach is the way to go I think.

Comment: @Kindread it is *much* more appropriate to use `dynamic_cast<>` for this and check it for NULL before firing the method. You're correct.

Comment: Not being one to avoid specifics, the *specific* confines of this question make this answer plausible. The OP specifically said he *knew* there was a `Door*` at `[i][j][k]`, and as such, a static cast *will* work and cause no ill-effects. Were it *unknown* and not a `Door*` the compiler would happily encode a call to `Door::isOpen` passing a non-`Door*` as `this`. The call grabs a value from memory where it thinks the `bool` behind `isOpen()` resides, and if you're lucky, *not* fault. But as I said, the OP says he "knows" its a `Door*`. Therefore, it works, but `dynamic_cast<>` is "right" imo.

Answer (score 2):

Consider polymorphic casting as supported by the language using `dynamic_cast<>` For references it will throw an exception (`std::bad_cast`) but for *pointers* if the target type is not compatible it will simply return NULL, so... assuming your base class and its derivations are indeed polymorphic (i.e. at least one virtual method):

```
Door* pDoor = dynamic_cast<Door*>(vector[i][j][k]);
if (pDoor)
    pDoor->isOpen();
```

Comments about the design withheld. Opinions are like... yeah. everyone has one.